# Detect IP address change of logged in user

Tags: php, security, ip-address

While using the cPanel of my hosting provider, I switched my internet connection from one network to another, when I clicked a link on my cPanel after switching my connection I was presented with the message:

> Your IP address has changed. Please log in again.

I was wondering how to detect such IP address change in order to provide such security in my website with PHP!!

Comment: Lookout with your "security" improvement, it will hinder users that use IPv6 when they swap over to a different temporary ip address

Comment: Good point, thanks for stating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is simple... when logging in, you create `$_SESSION` object... and just keep ip in that object `$_SESSION['user_ip']`, and in authentication / verify function (you have to have one), compare that ip with current (`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`).

And if you wan't to make it without user interaction, you need to make some periodic ajax requests.

PS. I hate portals that check IP. You can't damn stay logged in, as most of providers (all GSM ones, France Telecom etc etc) have dynamic ips that change every few (max 24) hours.

Comment: Yeah you are right it can also have a down side... I thought of such solution, I was wondering if it is optimal (best practice)!!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the IP address of the browser in PHP with the following:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

If you store that in the users session, you can validate that their IP hasn't changed. If it changes ... log them out with a warning message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

then you can throw in a if statement. Something like so,

```
if($ip == $_SESSION['username']) {
echo "User logged in";
} else die("IP address has changed, try again later");
```